# Spring Boot SAML with Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to implement SSO with Microsoft Azure from Spring Boot. The application uses local metadata stored on the server (it's deployed in a CentOS virtual machine with a custom client domain, and the server used for deploying the war is Tomcat 9).

The actual problem: after the first login (which is successful) and a couple of refreshes or closing the browser several times it crashes with two different errors:
[the first error after a successful login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdmqN.png) and the
[second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvuWv.png)

Below you can see my implementation of SAML in the security package.
All the fields are added as values from my [application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zkrl.png)

My SAML config class:

```java
@Configuration
public class SamlSecurityConfig {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SamlSecurityConfig.class);
  @Value("${saml.keystore.location}")
  private String samlKeystoreLocation;

  @Value("${saml.keystore.password}")
  private String samlKeystorePassword;

  @Value("${saml.keystore.alias}")
  private String samlKeystoreAlias;

  @Value("${saml.idp}")
  private String defaultIdp;

  @Value("${saml.metadata.location}")
  private String metadataLocation;

  @Bean
  public EmptyStorageFactory emptyStorageFactory() {
    return new EmptyStorageFactory();
  }

  @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
  public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
    return new StaticBasicParserPool();
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new CustomSAMLAuthenticationProvider();
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLContextProvider contextProvider() {
    SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProviderImpl = new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    contextProviderImpl.setStorageFactory(emptyStorageFactory());
    return contextProviderImpl;
  }

  @Bean
  public static SAMLBootstrap samlBootstrap() {
    return new SAMLBootstrap();
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
    return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
  }

  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
      WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl consumerImpl = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
      consumerImpl.setMaxAuthenticationAge(3600);
    return consumerImpl;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("hokWebSSOprofileConsumer")
  public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfileConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public SingleLogoutProfile logoutProfile() {
    return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader.getResource(samlKeystoreLocation);
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
    passwords.put(samlKeystoreAlias, samlKeystorePassword);
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, samlKeystorePassword, passwords, samlKeystoreAlias);
  }

  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
    WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    return webSSOProfileOptions;
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
    SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
    samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
    return samlEntryPoint;
  }

  @Bean
  public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
    return extendedMetadata;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("okta")
  public ExtendedMetadataDelegate oktaExtendedMetadataProvider() throws MetadataProviderException {
    File metadata = null;
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader.getResource(metadataLocation);
    try {
      metadata = new File(storeFile.getFile(), "sso.xml");
      log.info("The XML was parsed successful!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      log.error("Error on parsing the XML file!");
    }
    FilesystemMetadataProvider provider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(metadata);
    provider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate emd = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(provider, extendedMetadata());
    emd.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    return emd;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("metadata")
  public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException, ResourceException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(oktaExtendedMetadataProvider());
    CachingMetadataManager metadataManager = new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    metadataManager.setDefaultIDP(defaultIdp);
    return metadataManager;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("saml")
  public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return successRedirectHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("saml")
  public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
    failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
    return failureHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return successLogoutHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
    logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
    return logoutHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(), logoutHandler());
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(), new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
        new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
  }

  @Bean
  public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
    return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), VelocityFactory.getEngine());
  }

  @Bean
  public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
    return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
  }

  @Bean
  public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
    ArrayList<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();
    bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
    bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
    return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
  }
}
```

The web security config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${saml.sp}")
    private String samlAudience;

    @Value("${saml.idp}")
    private String defaultIdp;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saml")
    private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler samlAuthSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saml")
    private SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler samlAuthFailureHandler;

    @Value("${saml.metadata.location}")
    private String metadataLocation;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter;

    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata;

    @Autowired
    private KeyManager keyManager;

    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId(samlAudience);
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata);
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(true);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager);
        // metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(samlAudience);

        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(samlAuthSuccessHandler);
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(samlAuthFailureHandler);
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"), samlDiscovery()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"), samlEntryPoint));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"), samlLogoutFilter));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/getUsers").permitAll().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.logout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

The metadata file that was provided by microsoft azure:

```xml
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="_e5dc3ca1-bdef-4e69-99f8-367d2645e58e" entityID="https://sts.windows.net/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/">
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#_e5dc3ca1-bdef-4e69-99f8-367d2645e58e">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>8jc/wHi+O7dzGLgvBIwVvuxZAPaTCpw9hC2Jr0eWnRA=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>Signature</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>Certificate</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <RoleDescriptor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xsi:type="fed:SecurityTokenServiceType" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>Certificate</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <auth:DisplayName>Name</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>The mutable display name of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier">
                <auth:DisplayName>Subject</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>An immutable, globally unique, non-reusable identifier of the user that is unique to the application for which a token is issued.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
                <auth:DisplayName>Given Name</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>First name of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
                <auth:DisplayName>Surname</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Last name of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
                <auth:DisplayName>Display Name</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Display name of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/nickname">
                <auth:DisplayName>Nick Name</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Nick name of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant">
                <auth:DisplayName>Authentication Instant</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>The time (UTC) when the user is authenticated to Windows Azure Active Directory.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod">
                <auth:DisplayName>Authentication Method</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>The method that Windows Azure Active Directory uses to authenticate users.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
                <auth:DisplayName>ObjectIdentifier</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Primary identifier for the user in the directory. Immutable, globally unique, non-reusable.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
                <auth:DisplayName>TenantId</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Identifier for the user's tenant.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
                <auth:DisplayName>IdentityProvider</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Identity provider for the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <auth:DisplayName>Email</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Email address of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups">
                <auth:DisplayName>Groups</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Groups of the user.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/accesstoken">
                <auth:DisplayName>External Access Token</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Access token issued by external identity provider.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/expiration">
                <auth:DisplayName>External Access Token Expiration</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>UTC expiration time of access token issued by external identity provider.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/openid2_id">
                <auth:DisplayName>External OpenID 2.0 Identifier</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>OpenID 2.0 identifier issued by external identity provider.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/groups.link">
                <auth:DisplayName>GroupsOverageClaim</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Issued when number of user's group claims exceeds return limit.</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role">
                <auth:DisplayName>Role Claim</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Roles that the user or Service Principal is attached to</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
            <auth:ClaimType xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/wids">
                <auth:DisplayName>RoleTemplate Id Claim</auth:DisplayName>
                <auth:Description>Role template id of the Built-in Directory Roles that the user is a member of</auth:Description>
            </auth:ClaimType>
        </fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
        <fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint>
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/wsfed</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint>
        <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/wsfed</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
    </RoleDescriptor>
    <RoleDescriptor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xsi:type="fed:ApplicationServiceType" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>Certificate</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <fed:TargetScopes>
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://sts.windows.net/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </fed:TargetScopes>
        <fed:ApplicationServiceEndpoint>
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/wsfed</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </fed:ApplicationServiceEndpoint>
        <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
            <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/wsfed</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
    </RoleDescriptor>
    <IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>Certificate</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/saml2"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/saml2"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b0e7247-e0d5-44bf-8ed1-d01b18d16ca2/saml2"/>
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Comment: Hello @jurkovan , If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Error:  message SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing error may come with different cause.

**Solution**

```
   Your AssertionConsumerServiceURL should be AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://source.com/saml/SSO"
```

Reference: [What is the reason for below error while implementing SAML SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607621/what-is-the-reason-for-below-error-while-implementing-saml-sso)

Please also go through this solution it might be help also: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12768674/saml-protocol-message-was-not-signed-skipping-xml-.html